# Detecting whether page is navigated to or off C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my WPF application i have multiple pages.
One page is called "startup" and this is the one shown most of the time.
An NFC-Reader is running in the background on a thread and everytime you scan a card, it executes code.

My navigation works by having a class called "InstanceContainer.cs" which basically just holds all the instances to my pages which i then navigate to using (for example) `NavigationService.Navigate(InstanceContainer.startup());`

However i want it to only execute said code, when "startup" is shown while a card is scanned. My idea would be to just set a public bool like `public bool startupShown;` inside of "startup" which is then checked for in the thread that runs the NFC-Scanning.
But how do i neatly update this bool? Of course it could be updated manually on every buttonclick that leads away and to "startup", but there has to be a better way than that.

I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.navigating?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) but didn't quite understand it nor could i get it to work.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you navigated using the viewmodel first approach then you could put  your code in the startupviewmodel. When the user navigates away dispose startupviewmodel.

Comment: @Andy What would that look like? I have no idea on how to implement this, i'm sorry

Comment: You could easy google examples of viewmodel first navigation. If you tried. https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `Page`'s `IsLoaded` property to determine whether it's currently loaded and displayed in the `Frame`.

This property can however not be accessed directly from a background thread so you could either add your own field or property to the start page and handle the `Loaded` and `Unloaded` events to set it...:

```
public partial class StartupPage : Page
{
    public bool startupShown;

    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += (s, e) => startupShown = true;
        Unloaded += (s, e) => startupShown = false;
    }
}
```

...or use the dispatcher to access the built-in `Loaded` property from the background thread:

```
Page page = InstanceContainer.startup();
bool isloaded = page.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => page.IsLoaded);
```